# People all over the world / People from all over the world

Tags: grammaticality

An example in Collins Dictionary:

> ...the letters she received from **people all over the world.**

But if I write:

> ...the letters she received from people **from** all over the world.

Is it correct?

Further, I often come across these phrases:

> doctors **from** all over Europe.
>
> news **from** across the world.

Please explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It can be decomposed according to rules you’re familiar with.

“People all over the world” means people who are scattered and located all over the world. It could be understood as “People, who are all over the world, ...”.

“People from all over the world” means people who originated from or were born in places all over the world. It could be understood as “People, who are from all over the world, ...”.

Both cases are of a noun being modified by an adjective (a prepositional phrase, in the second) that directly follows it.